# WebRTC iOS Audio Chat

Tags: ios, audio, webrtc, callkit

I am creating a voice only (no video) chat application. I have created my own node.js/socket.io based server for signaling.

For WebRTC, I am using the following pod: https://cocoapods.org/pods/WebRTC

I have been successful in creating peer connection, adding local stream, setting local/remote sdp, and send/receive ice candidates. The "didAddStream" delegate method is also called successfully having audio tracks but I am stuck here. I don't know what should I do with the audio track. What should be the next step? How would I send/receive audio on both sides?

Also, if I integrate CallKit, what changes do I need to make.

Comment: Hi. what have you used to create audio stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got stuck on this one too. You have to retain the `RTCMediaStream` object in order for the audio to play. You don't need to do anything with the `RTCAudioTrack`, it will play automatically. I simply assign it to property so it can get retained. See my example here: https://github.com/redfearnk/WebRTCVideoChat/blob/master/WebRTCVideoChat/WebRTCClient.swift#L143

Comment: Yes, that's what I found finally. You don't have to do anything, the audio will automatically start playing.

I am planning to write a blog about WebRTC in iOS native apps (using swift) with a standalone Node.JS socket server integrated with CallKit.

Thank you very much for your answer though.

Comment: Great idea! I'd love to see it

Comment: Loca RTCAudioTrack starts playing automatically to. Do you know how to turn off it locally? Because I hear myself.

Comment: I am trying to implement VoIP with call recording. How difficult is that? How to implement server-side code and client-side(swift) code. Would be great help if you can share anything.

Comment: please post the link to blog here @AftabBaig

Comment: @AftabBaig Do you have an example for this Audio Call? Please share with me. I am getting stuck on this.

Comment: @ParthPatel sorry for the late reply. I am no more working on this project so it is not in my machine currently. I will send you the code in a day or 2 if that works.

Comment: @AftabBaig Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @AftabBaig if it's possible, please share the code with me as well. Thanks. You can send it to my emai: eddie.marvin116@gmail.com