# How to send Microphone and InApp Audio CMSampleBuffer to webRTC in swift?

Tags: swift, webrtc, replaykit

I am working on-screen broadcast application. I want to send my screen recording on WebRTC server.

```
override func processSampleBuffer(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, with sampleBufferType: RPSampleBufferType) {
        //if source!.isSocketConnected {
            switch sampleBufferType {
            case RPSampleBufferType.video:
                // Handle video sample buffer
                source?.processVideoSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
                break
            case RPSampleBufferType.audioApp:
                // Handle audio sample buffer for app audio
                source?.processInAppAudioSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)

                break
            case RPSampleBufferType.audioMic:
                // Handle audio sample buffer for mic audio
                source?.processAudioSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
                break
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
    }


// VideoBuffer Sending Method
func startCaptureLocalVideo(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {

        let _pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        if let pixelBuffer = _pixelBuffer {
            let rtcPixelBuffer = RTCCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
            let timeStampNs = CMTimeGetSeconds(CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)) * 1000000000
            let rtcVideoFrame = RTCVideoFrame(buffer: rtcPixelBuffer, rotation: RTCVideoRotation._90, timeStampNs: Int64(timeStampNs))

            localVideoSource!.capturer(videoCapturer!, didCapture: rtcVideoFrame)
        }

    }
```

I got success to send VIDEO Sample Buffer on WebRTC but I am getting stuck in AUDIO part.

I did not find any way how to send AUDIO buffer to WebRTC.

Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Your provided code is vague. What is `source`, who calls `startCaptureLocalVideo` ? If you are using a 3rd service, check their documentation first to see if you can push audio frames.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46308907/5923606 did you check this?.

Comment: @TonyNguyen startCaptureLocalVideo is not any third party service. It's my custom method to send my video buffer to WebRTC and No issue with the Video part. There is no service to send the Audio buffer to WebRTC.

Comment: @ugur Yes, I have checked it. I have implemented Audio Chat and it's working fine. This problem is for Broadcast Extension. How to Send Audio SampleBuffer to WebRTC?

Comment: @ParthPatel Are you able to record the webRTC stream audio video?

Comment: @Hardik1344 I have made some changes in WebRTC framework for the audio stream. WebRTC is only supported video stream you have to customise WebRTC framework.

Comment: Ok, so after customization are you able to record audio and video stream?
And are you using google webRTC framework for ios?

Comment: @Hardik1344 Yes absolutely right. I used the framework file of WebRTC no use of any pod. You can get this framework file from WebRTC Site.

Comment: @Parth Patel Thank you for your response, Can you please give me the link or URL from which you have downloaded the full source code for webRTC which include the .m and .h files.

Comment: I got the framework file which only includes the .h files

Comment: @Hardik1344 You can download opensource code from here https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/

Comment: @ParthPatel Hi, I currently have the same problem and being struggling for days to solve it. Video is working ok, but I cant get results with audio. Can you please share your implementation for sending audio from CMSampleBuffer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MileDev I have made some changes in the WebRTC framework for the audio stream. WebRTC has only supported video streams you have to customize the WebRTC framework.
Sorry not able to share code due to privacy.

Comment: @ParthPatel thank you for your answer. Yes, Im aware WebRTC framework need to be customized. This fork already did that: https://github.com/pixiv/webrtc/blob/87.0.4280.142-pixiv0/README.pixiv.en.md
I was thinking that maybe you used this fork. I followed their guideline but from some reason outgoing audio stops working when app goes background.

Comment: @MileDev You are doing good. I think background mode does not affect Broadcast Extension because It is a totally separate part from the application and application life cycle does not affect extension. You can print out extension logs and trace and find problems. My code will not help you here because I have implemented it as per my Customised WebRTC framework requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for that, just come to this link and follow the guideline:
https://github.com/pixiv/webrtc/blob/branch-heads/pixiv-m78/README.pixiv.md

WebRTC team is no longer to support native framework, so we need to modify WebRTC source code and re-build it to use inside another app.

Luckily, I found the person who fork source code from WebRTC project and he update the function that pass CMSampleBuffer from Broadcast extension to RTCPeerConnection.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)